# Multiple layers, master pivot point

Tags: mesh

I have a scene with multiple layers, even layers with sublayers(empty with layers within).

When I import this model into Unity3D the pivot point is in the original cube, even though in Blender each part has their own pivot point.

How can I modify this "master pivot point", so I can tell Unity3D where it should put the pivot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

In object mode you can create an "Empty" and put all the other layers inside the Empty, Unity3D will use the pivot point of the Empty because it is the outermost layer.

All you have to do is position the pivot point in the Empty.